# Пишет что бот не отвечает в дс

Tags: python, discord

вроде всё работает
вот код

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import random
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
BOT_TOKEN = ""

@Bot.slash_command(description="Добавление эмодзи")
async def реякция(ctx, messege_id,reaction):
 await ctx.reaction(reaction)
 emb = discord.Embed(title="Эмодзи успешно добавлено", color=0x272727)
 await ctx.response_send_message(embed=emb)
@Bot.slash_command(description="Рандом лут с машины")
async def лут (ctx):
 item = [ "knife_chance" ,
"sword_chance"]
 send(random.choice(item))
Bot.run (BOT_TOKEN)
```

код ошибки:

```
 File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 124, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 982, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Discrod bot Popytka 1\main.py", line 20, in лут
    send(random.choice(item))
    ^^^^
NameError: name 'send' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1114, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 375, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 132, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'send' is not defined
```

вот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В логах должны быть ошибка скинь сюда